# Why is the tableview nil?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewController and inside of that I have a TableView. After I get the data with an Alamofire Request I reload the data of the TableView and there is where it crashes because the tableView is nil.

```
class TeamsVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

var terminArr = [Termin]()
override func viewDidLoad() {        
    TerminResource.getTerminsByUsername(username: "SonnyBlackzz"){
        response in

        self.terminArr = response
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.terminArr.count;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)

    print(self.terminArr[indexPath.row].name)

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.terminArr[indexPath.row].name

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Have you connected the table view to its outlet in the storyboard - if you use storyboards, that is?

Comment: Have you connected your IBOutlet to the tableView?

Comment: have you set the tableview cell identifier in the storyboard..?

Comment: thank you it wasn't connected to the outlet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have three options maybe help you .

1-Make sure that you have connected the outlet to your table view .

2-you can change your inherit to be as below

```
class TeamsVC: UITableViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
.
.
.
}
```

the you will have easily access

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

3- You may have to init it programatically

first

```
var tableView: UITableView  =   UITableView()
```

then in viewdidload

```
tableView = UITableView(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.Plain)
tableView.delegate      =   self
tableView.dataSource    =   self
```